# Error: Maven: Non parseable POM ... expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Seems like not a hard issue at all.

POM:

[image]

Line underlined in red in the error line.

Comment: You should fill in the dependency.

Comment: I did have it filled in and removed it to see if the error still occurred and it did. Whatever in it does not change the error.

Comment: after you filled it, what error are you getting?

Comment: same error as the one now.

Comment: Then you should show what you filled in that still had the error, because this is *obviously* wrong (no inner content) and what you had before still might be wrong.

Comment: updated it with the content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I popped this into eclipse and it looks fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CENSORED</groupId>
    <artifactId>NeoImport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In your screen capture your syntax highlight for the `<?xml?>` is off at the end. Do you happen to have a newline character before that very first line?

Or if you copied pasted it from somewhere else that formats the text differently than your IDE  (i.e. UNIX/OSX vs Dos/Windows) then that may cause issues too.

Comment: Yeah it was my stupid self having that extra space. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, it's always the simple things that getchya ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you can build your project in your local but you cannot build in Jenkins environment:

- Check if there are any problematic character at the specified line:

Resolution: open your pom file in an editor like np++ to show special characters and removed those characters from your code.

- If not, its Possibly be due to SCM conflicts.

Resolution: Go to Project Build configuration and change the "Check-Out Strategy" within Source Code Management.
Use the strategy to first clean checkout instead of just update.
Very Likely it should fix the problem that might have arose due to SCM conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I get an error:

```
unexpected character in markup < (position: END_TAG seen ...</developerConnection>
```

solved it by cutting the parent element of developerConnection and pasting it again!

Answer (score 0):

Check for special characters inside POM.xml, if you find remove.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30550261)